# How do I update BuildNumber using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

I would like to update the Build.BuildNumber variable from a PowerShell script as a build step.

I've tried:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BUILD_BUILDNUMBER]1.2.3.4"
```

and

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Build.BuildNumber]1.2.3.4"
```

This has not worked.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You'd need to use the Update Build Number function:

```
Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]1.0.0.$($env:Build_BuildId)"
```

BuildNumber is a special case. Other variables can be overwritten using the setvariable macro you mentioned.

It will overwrite the actual build number as well so after your statement you Build Number in the Builds overview will reflect the new number.

There are two tasks which may help you out here. My own [Variable Toolbox and the Variables Task pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=variable&target=VSTS&sortBy=Relevance). With those you can set variables to a specific value and while my own task will auto-correct the command to set the buildnumber when that variable is passed as output variable. The Task pack has a special task to set the build number.

Comment: Docs are here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md

Comment: This throws an exception: Unable to process logging event:##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]. Could it be .88 of the agent is required? I'm using .83?

Comment: That or it only works in ps custom tasks, not random scripts.