# How to create a new Tag with Azure Pipeline?

Tags: git, azure, azure-pipelines, visual-studio-app-center

I have a pipeline in Azure, that is triggered when a commit or merge is done in master branch.

This pipeline builds the project, sign the app and release a new version to App Center.

How can I do to create a new tag in the repo, associated with that release version and that branch?

Comment: is this helps? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ATP.ATP-GitTag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting Git Tag from Azure Devops Build Pipeline on Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59226055/setting-git-tag-from-azure-devops-build-pipeline-on-complete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry we do not have any build-in feature or official task to support this currently.

You could take a look at this 3rd-party extension--[Tag\Branch Git on Release](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jabbera.git-tag-on-release-task&ssr=false#overview) which fit your needs:

> This is an Azure DevOps plugin that will git tag or branch artifact
>   source code with the release name. This makes it very easy to patch in
>   the future if needed.
>
> **When the task runs it finds all linked artifacts that originated from a TfsGit source repo and tags or branches them with the release
>   name.** This is meant to be super simple. Just drop in your release
>   pipeline and go.