# Getting azure repo taggine error during build pipeline

Tags: git, azure-devops

I am trying to tag the active git branch with the build number so that we can know what all code changes have got into the build. Referring to this [Setting Git Tag from Azure Devops Build Pipeline on Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59226055/setting-git-tag-from-azure-devops-build-pipeline-on-complete) I made entries in the YAML file. Below is the YAML code changes.

```
steps:
  - checkout: 'self'
    clean: true
    persistCredentials: true

  - script: |
      git tag Build_$(Build.BuildId)
      git push origin Build_$(Build.BuildId)
    workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```

The pipeline build succeeds and I am able to see the tag applied
[image]

However, when I see the build logs I see below error. I don't understand what is the problem

### [error]To https://dev.azure.com/{Org}/{Project}/_git/{Repo}

### [error] * [new tag]           Build_10691 -> Build_10691

Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: Looks like it's Git just reporting the progress to the standard error stream. Can you try and modify the `git push` command in your script to `git push -q origin Build_$(Build.BuildId)`?

Comment: @YanSklyarenko Consider adding that as answer instead of comment~ Just a reminder, at least in my test the `-q` options works like a charm to resolve the error.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT thanks for testing that! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is known to report the progress status of the `push` command to the error stream. Search for `--progress` option [here in the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) for more details. You can suppress this behavior supplying the `-q` option to the `push` command, like this:

```
git push -q origin Build_$(Build.BuildId)
```

According to the `-q` option description:

> Suppress all output, including the listing of updated refs, unless an
>   error occurs. **Progress is not reported to the standard error stream.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: My heart felt Thank you very much Yan.